# How to combine all files in a new file

Tags: php

I want to add all my files that are under "`$myfiles`" variable in one file called "`combined.txt`" 
I did 
echo implode(`$myfile`);
But Im not sure how to make them create and go into a file called "`combined.txt`"

Comment: `implode()` is for joining strings, it has nothing to do with files.

Comment: Is there another way then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop to append the contents of each file to `combined.txt`.

```
file_put_contents("combined.txt", ""); // Empty the file first
foreach ($myfiles as $file) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    file_put_contents("combined.txt", $contents, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: In your script that wants to combine the files.

Comment: Actually I did it and it doesn't work, should I create a file called combined then run this code?

Comment: The script should create the file by itself. You may need to use a full pathname so the file is put in a directory that you have write permission to.